# Sending HTTP request line to jupyter with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, jupyter-notebook

I tried to send a HTTP request to my jupyter notebook with the help of the module [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) like this:

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8888))
    s.sendall(b'GET /api/contents HTTP/1.1 \n\n') # Maybe i didn't understand how HTTP requests work
    print(s.recv(1024))
```

Output(in the terminal where jupyter notebook was running):

```
Malformed HTTP message from 127.0.0.1: Malformed HTTP request line
```

And the data received is `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n\r\n`

And it says that it uses this delimiter `re.compile(b'\r?\n\r?\n')`

[`Jupyter Notebook Server API`](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-Notebook-Server-API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to supply any headers in your `HTTP` request, just terminate it with `\r\n\r\n` sequence:

```
s.sendall(b'GET /api/contents HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n')
```

`HTTP` uses `\r\n` sequence as a line-delimiter (like in Windows) and double sequence (`\r\n\r\n`) to mark the request headers end. So normally the request would look like

```
GET /api/contents HTTP/1.1\r\n
User-Agent: blablah\r\n
....\r\n
\r\n
<HERE GOES REQUEST BODY>
```